# error: invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

```
class Stack
{               
private:

    int tos;
    const int max = 10;    
    int a[max];
public:

    void push(int adddata);
    void pop();
    void printlist();
};
```

error: invalid use of non-static data member 'max'

whats wrong in the code, and please help me with proper correction. 
Thankyou

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is mandatory that the array size be known during compile time for non-heap allocation (not using `new` to allocate memory).

If you are using C++11, `constexpr` is a good keyword to know, which is specifically designed for this purpose. [Edit: As pointed out by @bornfree in comments, it still needs to be static]

```
static constexpr int max = 10;
```

So, use `static` to make it a compile time constant as others have pointed out.

Comment: Even in c++11, I think you can't just use constexpr. You will have to use static constexpr int max = 10.

Comment: Non-static data members cannot be `constexpr`. The comment above is correct.

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, max is a non-static member of Stack; so you can only access it as part of a Stack object. You are trying to access it as if it were a static member, which exists independently of any objects.

Hence you need to make it static.

```
static const int max = 10;
```

If the initialization is in the header file then each file that includes the header file will have a definition of the static member. Thus during the link phase you will get linker errors as the code to initialize the variable will be defined in multiple source files.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says make the data member static

```
static const int max = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make max a compile time constant:

```
static const int max = 10;
```

Comment: Not all compilers support that, it will have to be made `static const int max;` in header and `const int Stack::max = 10;` in the cpp file

Comment: @tejashs: the definition of `max` has to appear in the header too.

Comment: If you have a bad/old compiler you can also go and do 
`inline static const int max(){return 10; }`

Answer (score 0):

The Conceptual mistake that you are making is that you are trying to initialize values for the class in the class definition .This is the reason why constructors exist .Using a parametrized constructor set values of top of stack and its size.
When making the stack object pass the size of the stack to be created:

```
class Stack {               
private:
  int tos; 
  int a[max];

public:
  Stack(int s);
  void push(int adddata);
  void pop();
  void printlist();
};

Stack::Stack(int s) {
  tos=-1;
  max=s;
}
```